# sencha touch :: associated store/model pair not creating instance name function

Tags: model, associations, sencha-touch, store

i have a big problem setting up an associated store/model concept.

I have the models/store

```
app.models.User = Ext.regModel('app.models.User', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',         type: 'int'},
        {name: 'userID',    type: 'string'},
        {name: 'userName',  type: 'string'}
    ],

    associations: [
        {type: 'hasMany', model: 'app.models.Friend', name:'friends', associationKey:'friends'},
    ]
});

app.models.UserFriendsList = Ext.regModel('app.models.UserFriendsList', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',         type: 'int'},
        {name: 'userID',     type: 'string'},
        {name: 'userName',  type: 'string'}
    ],

    belongsTo: 'app.models.User',

    associations: [
        {type: 'hasMany', model: 'app.models.Friend',    name: 'friend'}
    ]
});

app.models.Friend = Ext.regModel('app.models.Friend', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',         type: 'int'},
        {name: 'userID',    type: 'string'},
        {name: 'userName',  type: 'string'}
    ],
   belongsTo: 'app.models.UserFriendsList',
});

app.stores.userStore = new Ext.data.Store({

    model: 'app.models.User',

    data:[
        {
            "id":                 "01", 
            "userName":         "Username"

            "friends": [
                {    "id":                 "02", 
                    "userName":         "Friend 1"
                },
                {    "id":                 "03", 
                    "userName":         "Friend 2"
                },
            ]

        }
    ]
});
```

I then use

```
var currentUser = app.stores.User.getAt(0); 
console.log(currentUser);
var friends = currentUser.friends().getAt(0);
console.log(friends);
```

to trace some debug information about the currently loaded user.

When I use the 'associationKey'-parameter without the 'name'-parameter the trace shows that the data is fetched correctly into the data-part of the traced object 'currentUser'. But there is no function friends() to use. I only get the error

*`TypeError: Result of expression 'currentUser.friends' [undefined] is not a function.`*

When I use the 'name'-parameter without the 'associationKey'-parameter (or both parameters) the instance function friends() is created but no data is fetched into the object so I can't use it.

What is wrong with my code? Or where is my misunderstanding of concept?

THNX!!!

EDIT: please have a look into my files: http://www.box.net/shared/n4h3rdp1499ihx990v3h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a few problems with your model declarations and [has many associations](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.data.HasManyAssociation).

First, your model names should be just simple statements, not doted fully qualified objects.  It makes the declarations easier.

```
app.models.User = Ext.regModel('app.models.User', {
```

Should be:

```
app.models.User = Ext.regModel('User', {
```

Second, you need to have fields that relate the ids to each other properly named.

```
app.models.Friend = Ext.regModel('Friend', {
fields: [
    {name: 'user_id', type: 'int'},
    .....
],
```

Now that your model is named `User`, and your Friend model references `user_id`, Sencha Touch will automatically use the association properly.

Third, you need to fix your Association declaration.  You added the property associationKey to the association. Which doesn't exist in the docs and the model should be just 'Friend' after the first point that I mentioned.

```
associations: [
    {type: 'hasMany', 
     model: 'Friend', 
     name:'friends', 
    },
]
```

Fourth, to get the friends you need to perform a load on the store. `currentUser.friends().load().getAt(0);`

You can get fancy and declare different foriegn keys as different names but at this point I would just get the basic example up and working.

Sencha has a good tutorial about getting started with [associations and validations](http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-validations-and-associations-in-sencha-touch).

Comment: +1 on the load()-comment, have been looking for this the whole day. I think it's not properly defined in the docs.

Comment: @martijn yeah, it definitely isn't clear that you have to do that. Using the association properties results in a returned Ext.Store with autoload set to false, so you have to do the load yourself.

Comment: hey, thanx! I will try it out now. do I need to load the store every time or just once?

Comment: hm I still get 
**bold**TypeError: Result of expression 'currentFriend.friends' [undefined] is not a function.**bold**
when I perform 
`code`
var currentFriend = app.stores.userStore.findRecord('id', id);
var theFriends = currentFriend.friends().load();
`code`
and there are still no associated stores generated nor store objects filled.

Comment: I don't what can be causing those problems. Try debugging using a desktop browser. The association objects are on the object as `currentUser.associations()`. The `friends()` function should by on the prototype for the object as well, see if it exists. I would start there, and if worse comes to worse trace through the sencha code to find out why your objects aren't being created properly

Comment: thx! there is definitly a "friendsStore" but when I call currentUser.friends().load().getAt(0) I only get the error "You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.".
In my User-Store I use the data-attribute to feed the store, so there is no URL to specify...